# ¿Como retornar una vista dinamicamente con spring boot?

Tags: html5, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, thymeleaf

Como puedo retornar una vista dinamicamente por medio de un controller en spring boot

Este es mi index.html

```
  <html>
  <head>
     <title>prueba</title>
  </head>
  <body>
     <div th:replace="${contenido}"></div>
  </body>
  </html>
```

Esta es mi pagina1.html

```
<div>
  pagina 1
</div>
```

Esta es mi pagina2.html

```
<div>
  pagina 2
</div>
```

Estos son mis controllers

```
@GetMapping("/")
public String showIndex(Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("contenido", "pagina1");
    return "index";
}

@GetMapping("/prueba")
public String showIndex(Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("contenido", "pagina2");
    return "index";
}
```

No me funciona en que sera que este fallando

Comment: Estoy bastante seguro de que puedo responder a tu pregunta pero tengo el problema de que interpreto tu pregunta de varias maneras. ¿Podrías mejorar la redacción de la misma?

Answer (score 0):

Debes indicarle a tu `layout` que va a recibir una vista:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>prueba</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div th:replace="${view} :: container"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

En tus `controllers` debes indicar que regresas un `ModelAndView`:

```
@GetMapping("/prueba")
public ModelAndView showIndex(Model model) {
    ModelAndView layout = "index";
    layout.addObject("contenido","pagina2");
    return layout;
}
```

Saludos